# Create a folder in Java without knowing if user is using OS-X or Windows

Tags: java

I'm creating a new folder by client side using java, but I don't know how to do, because an user could run application in OS-X ambient or windows.
I wrote this:

```
Utility.createDirectory(directory.getText() + "/Archivio");
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(directory.getText() + "/Archivio/" + fileName);
fos.write(bytex);
```

but this works only in OS-X and linux. How can I do?

Comment: what is `Utility`?

Comment: A class that contains this method:
public static boolean createDirectory(String serverpath){
            File serverpathdir = new File(serverpath);
            return serverpathdir.mkdir();

        }

Comment: What does `directory.getText()` return, have you debugged it?

Comment: It should work the same on Windows regardless of which file path separator you use.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, are you sure? I can't test it on Windows!

Comment: If you can't test on Windows, I'd be reluctant against releasing on Windows. Java is pretty cross platform, but it still has it's hiccups.

Often it successfully abstracts over file seperators, othertimes it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: I suggest installing a virtual machine running windows on a machine you have available for testing. There is likely to be other gotchas as Ryan suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows API used by Java normalizes the path and translates forward to backward slashes so windows should not be a problem for it. Simply this should work:

```
new File("/path/to/folder").mkdir();
```

Comment: AFAIK, it is not that Java normalizes it, it is that the Windows API used by Java allows both \ and / as path separators.

Comment: edited answer as per Mark's comment. Thank you Mark

Answer (score 0):

let's try to use File.separator instead of using "/". Your code will looks like:

```
Utility.createDirectory(directory.getText() + File.separator +"Archivio");
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(directory.getText() + File.separator +"Archivio"+File.separator + fileName);
fos.write(bytex);
```